How can I get round trip time of ccxt API call?
I am able to get last response headers and body from the ccxt library, but how do I get the time between sending the request to the Exchange and getting it back? I am already measuring time of the ccxt function call in my code, but that includes parsing the response etc., which might take some extra time (the response of binance.fetchBidsAsks() is above 300 kB). I want only to measure the round trip time, i.e. until the message was delivered to my computer. Does the ccxt library provide this information somewhere, or do I have to modify it? (And possibly how?)

If it uses fetch(), can you supply your own instance of fetch() and override what they use? Many libraries let you do this
